# Triangle Inequality for a type of Sobolev space norm

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

I am attempting to show the triangle inequality holds for the following norm, which is defined as: $||f|| = \bigg( \int_0^1 (|f|^2 + |f'|^2) \ dx  \bigg)^{1/2} \\$.

My attempt thus far; I am confused on where to go next? Any help would be great.

$\begin{align*}
    ||f+g||^2 &= \int_0^1 |f+g|^2+ |f'+g'|^2 \ dx \\
    &= \int_0^1 |f|^2 + 2|fg| +|g|^2 |f'|^2 + 2|f'g'| + |g'|^2 \ dx \\
    &= \int_0^1 |f|^2 + |f'|^2 \ dx + \int_0^1 |g|^2 + |g'|^2 \ dx + 2 \int_0^1 |fg|+|f'g'| \ dx \\
    \end{align*}$

Comment: Please note that this is the simplest "Sobolev spaces" norm. It is why I have taken the liberty to mention Sobolev in your title, in order that later on people will have a specific keyword for it.

Comment: @JeanMarie I have looked at the possible duplicate but I was wondering if there was an easier way of reaching the inequality without completing the square.

Comment: Here is another simpler reference https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1797585

Comment: Finally, here is a clever (and short) proof by Copper.hat: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/409923

Comment: @JeanMarie thank you very very much. I appreciate it lots!!